# Android: Checking If Arraylist is Empty JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Im using https://github.com/thest1/LazyList as my listview

i wonder how will i check if the listview is Empty or when null?

this is the sample codes from the post Execute

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml



            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new LvOrderSumAdapter(OrderSum.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.getAdapter().getCount();
            String count = ""+listview.getAdapter().getCount(); 
            items.setText(count);



            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();


        }
```

Please help !
 I tried this code from what i've searched

```
    if(!arraylist.isEmpty()){
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrderSummary);

            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new LvOrderSumAdapter(OrderSum.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.getAdapter().getCount();
            String count = ""+listview.getAdapter().getCount(); 
            items.setText(count);
            //o_total.setText("aaa");


            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }else{  String msg = "No records found in Database!";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Intent home_in = new Intent ( OrderSum.this,
                            Home.class ); 
                 startActivity(home_in); 
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);

            }
```

but i still got the error

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"
```

Comment: **"Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"** : The result you are getting is not a pure JSON string - it's JSON wrapped in HTML. The `<br` prefix is an HTML tag - check your server and change the return result so it isn't wrapped in HTML.

Comment: {"orders":[{"id":"1","ord_name":"Nestea Bottle","ord_desc":"Nestea in a bottle","ord_price":"15","ord_qty":"2","customer_id":"54feec24bff73","ord_num":"13211554feec24bff73","price_x_quan":"30.00","image":"http://192.168.43.52/MMOS/uploads/nestea_bottled.jpg","subtotal":"","imgimg":"uploads/nestea_bottled.jpg"}],"o_total":30} this is the JSON

Comment: Let me guess...is that what you see in a browser?

Comment: yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: The browser is stripping out the HTML which is why you don't see it. Think about it - every web page you look at with a browser has 100s or 1000s of HTML tags in it but you don't see them as they're used for formatting etc. Put a `Log.d(...)` line into your code to log the response from your server then look at logcat - you'll see your JSON string is actually wrapped in HTML. You need to change your server response so it returns a pure JSON string without the HTML wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a listView is null:

```
listView != null;
```

To check if a listView dont have elements:

```
listView.getAdapter().getCount()<=0;
```

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you print here the string value that you want to convert?

Comment: {"orders":[{"id":"1","ord_name":"Nestea Bottle","ord_desc":"Nestea in a bottle","ord_price":"15","ord_qty":"2","customer_id":"54feec24bff73","ord_num":"13211554feec24bff73","price_x_quan":"30.00","image":"http://192.168.43.52/MMOS/uploads/nestea_bottled.jpg","subtotal":"","imgimg":"uploads/nestea_bottled.jpg"}],"o_total":30} this is the JSON from url

Comment: There are no "<br" in your JSON string. You are not seeing in the rigth local